L2TP VPN not working
I have bought VPN router ER605. I have VDSL modem Zyxel, where I allowed DMZ to IP adress of router (192.168.10.49). On router (192.168.0.1) I set up VPN, as I found on youtube.

When I tried to connect VPN, it always end with this error.

can anybody please help me, what to do?
Here is the scheme:

thank you very much
